# Angular JS, Jquery, dropdown not populating the complex json data

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Please have a look at the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/y9hvyxOkdq1jPDKjHgYM?p=preview

1. Can any one help me to fix the code so that I can populate the customer dropdown with the options as per the data?
2. Right now I am trying to assign option value property of the dropdown to json "value"
   ( "value": "CU18257"). This "CU18257" will be given to dropdown option value.

   For example (*)

Is there any possibility for me to assign this json "value" to  some custom property like customerlable for the dropdown options, so that Angular js would generate the dropdown option values. and with that I can access simply customers[2], etc in my controller.

For example I want the dropdown to be poplated as follows:

```
<option value="0" customerlable= "CU18257"> </option>
<option value="1" customerlable= "----CU18257"> </option>
```

Comment: what does 'json value key value' mean?

Comment: I have edited my post. The following is not appearing in my above post, I don't know the reason.  so I am pasting that line here.                                                               For example (*)  <option value = "CU18257"> </option>                          Is it clear or shall I need to make any further clarifications?

Comment: The plunker site is down right now .. so I cannot see your code, but from my guess, you probably could use `ng-repeat` instead of `ng-options` to do what you want.

Comment: Have you tried `ng-repeat`([link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)) to generate the `option` list?

Comment: not yet with ng-repeat, as plunker is down I have put it jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/madasuk/83U97/. In my code I am appending options in jquery, I am not clear how to go head with ng-repeat in this case.

Comment: Sorry somehow the fiddle did not save correctly. I will update once I modify it correctly.

Comment: I am not sure no matter how many times I am updating the fiddle, it is not saving. Sorry for the inconvenience. I will try after while again with Fiddle, if plunker is not up and will update you.

Comment: Please use this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/madasuk/36rhX/10/

Comment: Tried with ng-repeat too by changing ng-options to ng-repeat but no success.